# DAX function to count total number of times an order number appears in a data table given a list of the unique order numbers

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a set of orders, each order has between 1 and 30 or so serial numbers in the order. The dataset has a row for each serial number, so sometimes the order number is repeated, as many times as there are serial numbers. I also have a table of all of the distinct order numbers, and I am looking to count how many serial numbers each order has. The serial numbers are "located" in different places, which meant I could not just sum them all up.

[Here is a snippet of the main data table with the order number on the left and serial numbers on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5eV9.png)

I've tried a few functions that are supposed to mimic SUMIF but I am either only able to get 0 or the sum of ALL of the serial numbers.

[Here is the most recent thing I've tried, as well as the list of unique order numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rFJB.png)

[Here is my data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUOPI.png)
[Here is the result when I tried the measure suggested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOAZG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it in a simple way! As far as I can understand, you have a model like this:

[image: Model View]

Then create a simple measure like this:

```
QtyInWorkOrder = COUNT(ListOfWorkOrders[SERIAL_NUM])
```

Then Test it on a table visual:

Put ORDER_NUMBER field on the ORDERS table into row field, Above measure into values field, Then final report looks like:

[image: Result]

Note: I partly copied your data!so actual result will look different on your report!

I hope This solves your problem!

Update:
Create a new measure and put it into your description! See picture below!
or
Just put calculate in your formula:

```
QtyInWorkOrder = CALCULATE(COUNT(ListOfWorkOrders[SERIAL_NUM]))
```

[image: DFER]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I believe that's a correct data model, but I'll edit my post with a screenshot of mine because when I used the measure you gave, all of the orders showed as the same number (I believe it's the total number of serial numbers)

Comment: Yes, It is! total serial numbers by production orders! It shows the same value because you are using it as calculated column! Then do it like this. Create a measure using my code! and Then put it into your field! Like this:YourQtyInWorkOrder = [QtyInWorkOrder]

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it's not split by production order, each production order in my unique list is showing 74604

Comment: I added a update screenshot at the bottom to show you how to do it! or as a 2nd solution, just put calculate in front of your formula: CALCULATE(COUNT(ListOfWorkOrders[SERIAL_NUM]))

Comment: You're welcome! Nice to hear it!